# как организовать роутинг

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Делаю роутинг и мне нужно что бы по клику на кнопку "Next Day" выводило погоду на следующий день

```js
<template>
  <div class="day">
    <h1>Details!</h1>
    <p>Date: {{$route.params.date}}</p>
    <p>Moonrise: {{$route.params.weather.astronomy[0].moonrise}}</p>
    <p>Moonset: {{$route.params.weather.astronomy[0].moonset}}</p>
    <p>Sunrise: {{$route.params.weather.astronomy[0].sunrise}}</p>
    <p>Sunset: {{$route.params.weather.astronomy[0].sunset}}</p>
    <p>Min Temperature today C: {{$route.params.weather.mintempC}}</p>
    <p>Max Temperature today C: {{$route.params.weather.maxtempC}}</p>
    <p>Min Temperature today F: {{$route.params.weather.mintempF}}</p>
    <p>Max Temperature today F: {{$route.params.weather.maxtempF}}</p>
    <router-link to="/"><md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Back to Home</md-button></router-link>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" @click="nextDay($route.params.date)">Next Day</md-button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'DayWeatherInfo',
  date(){
    return{}
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['cityInformation'])
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from){
      this.$route.params.date = to.params.date
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextDay (thisDay) {
      let day = new Date(thisDay)
      console.log(day.getDate()+1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать на кнопку Next Day тем же `<router-link>`, но с новым значением даты:

```
<template>
...
    <router-link to="/"><md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Back to Home</md-button></router-link>
    <router-link :to="nextDayRoute"><md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Next Day</md-button></router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

И добавить вычисляемое свойство для пути на следующий день:

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['cityInformation']),
    nextDayRoute() {
      let nextDay = new Date(thisDay)
      nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate()+1)
      return {name: '', params: {...this.$route.params, date = nextDay}}
    }
  },
```